# How to use accordion custom widget

Tags: flutter, accordion, custom-widgets

I used a custom widget for accordion but have no idea how it works I used classes to store the data but it comes out empty. I tried using both an index parsed through another listview and a hardcoded one but still doesn't display anything.

```
Accordion(
            title: receiptData.getVisitType(0),
            content: receiptData.getVisitDesc(),
          ),
```

[image: title]

[image: content]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'receiptClassData.dart';

ReceiptData receiptData = ReceiptData();

class Accordion extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String content;

  const Accordion({Key? key, required this.title, required this.content})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AccordionState createState() => _AccordionState();
}

class _AccordionState extends State<Accordion> {
  bool _showContent = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(children: [
        ListTile(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          onTap:(){
              setState(() {
                _showContent = !_showContent;
              });
            },
        ),
        _showContent
            ? Container(
          padding:
          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 15),
          child: Text(widget.content),
        )
            : Container()
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
Accordion(
            title: receiptData.getVisitType(),
            content: receiptData.getVisitDesc(),
          ),
```

receiptClassData

```
import 'receiptClass.dart';

int _receiptIndex = 0;

class ReceiptData {
  final List<Receipt> _receiptdata = [
    Receipt("Physical Therapy", "Walking\nKnee jumps\nFeeding fish", "Needs to do more memory training\nto take medication 3 times per day", 23.00, 10.50, 4.0),
    Receipt("Consultation","Jogging\nGardening\nRest", "Needs more sleep and not to skip medication", 23.00, 15.50, 3.5),
    Receipt("Physical Therapy","Swimming\nWalking\nGardening", "Needs more energy so more exercise is advised", 33.00, 25.00, 5.0),
    Receipt("Consultation","nil", "Medication to be taken daily as recommended on bottle", 55.00, 45.50, 1),
    Receipt("Consultation","Walking\nGardening\nWalking Dog", "Mental health has been affected, advised to do more hobbies instead of staying at home", 33.00, 100.50, 4.5),
  ];

  String getVisitType(){
    return _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].title;
  }

  String getVisitDesc(){
    return _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].titleDesc;
  }

  String getDoctorNotes(){
    return _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].doctorNotes;
  }

  double getCFees(){
    return _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].consultationFee;
  }

  double getMFees(){
    return _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].medicationFee;
  }

  double calcTotal(){
    return _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].consultationFee + _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].medicationFee;
  }

  double getRating(){
    return _receiptdata[_receiptIndex].rating;
  }

  int getIndex(){
    return _receiptIndex;
  }


}
```

added the receipt class as per requested

```
import 'dart:ui';

class Receipt {
  String title = "";
  String titleDesc = "";
  String doctorNotes = "";
  double consultationFee = 0.0;
  double medicationFee = 0.0;
  double rating = 0.0;

  Receipt(String rs, String rtd, String rdn, double rcf, double rmf, double rr){
    String title = rs;
    String titleDesc = rtd;
    String doctorNotes = rdn;
    double consultationFee = rcf;
    double medicationFee = rmf;
    double rating = rr;
  }


}
```

Comment: before calling Accordion print(receiptData.getVisitType(0)) and see what you got

Comment: I did it under widget build but it's empty

Comment: then problem maybe from this getVisitType() and getVisitDesc(), can you check if these methods are returning values

Comment: I added the class code in the question, it is supposed to be returning values

Comment: just before this Accordion(
            title: receiptData.getVisitType(),
            content: receiptData.getVisitDesc(),
          ),
Can you please print(receiptData.getVisitType()) and check if it is taking value?

Comment: still empty....

Comment: please share Receipt class

Comment: I just copy paste your code and everything is working fine with me checkout this https://dartpad.dev/?id=bbd3f10c2593f0add04dd770318b33f7

Comment: the link does not bring me to the same code as mine

Comment: yes i reduce some code for readability but other than that everything is fine